# No blocking, good execution plan, slow query: why?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that occasionally takes several minutes to complete. Several processes are running concurrently but there is no blocking (I'm running an extended events session, I can see blocking of other transactions, so the query to inspect the logged events is working).
Looking at the query plan cache, the execution plan is a good one: running it in SSMS, it takes less than 100 IOs, and there are no table or index scans.

There is the possibility that the users are getting a different plan, but if I add hints to use scans on all tables (and some are fairly large), it still returns in around 1 second. So the worst possible execution plan still wouldn't result in a query that takes several minutes.

Having ruled out blocking and a bad execution plan, What else can make a query slow ?

One thing worth pointing out is that SQL Server uses an indexed view we have created, although the code doesn't reference it (we're using SQL Server Enterprise). That indexed view has a covering index to support the query and it is being used - again, the execution plan is very good. The original query is using NOLOCK, and I observed that no locks are taken on any rows or pages of the indexed view either (so SQL Server respects our locking hints, even though it's accessing an indexed view instead of the underlying tables - good). This makes sense, otherwise I would have expected to see blocking.

We are using indexed views in some other queries but we reference them in SQL code (and specify NOLOCK, NOEXPAND). I've not seen any problems with those queries, and I'm not aware that there should be any difference between indexed views that we tell the optimizer to use and indexed views that the optimizer itself decides to use, but what I'm seeing suggests that there is.

Any thoughts ? Anything else I should be looking at ?

This is the query:

```
execute sp_executesql 
N'SELECT DISTINCT p.policy_id
           , p.name_e AS policy_name_e
           , p.name_l AS policy_name_l
FROM       patient_visit_nl_view AS pv
INNER JOIN swe_cashier_transaction_nl_view AS ct ON ct.patient_visit_id = pv.patient_visit_id
           AND ct.split_date_time IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN ar_invoice_nl_view AS ai ON ai.ar_invoice_id = ct.invoice_id
           AND ai.company_code = ''KOC''
           AND ai.transaction_status_rcd = ''TEMP''
INNER JOIN policy_nl_view p ON p.policy_id = ai.policy_id
WHERE      pv.patient_id = @pv__patient_id'
, N' @pv__patient_id uniqueidentifier'
, @pv__patient_id = '5D61EDF1-7542-11E8-BFCB-D89EF37315A2'
```

Note: views with suffix _nl_view select from the table with NOLOCK (the idea is we can change this in future without affecting the business tier code).

You can see the query plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJI9Lj_WH

IO stats:

```
Table 'policy'. Scan count 0, logical reads 9, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Locks taken (IS locks on the objects involved, nothing else):
[locks taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf47A.png)

Below the relevant part of the indexed view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT      ai.ar_invoice_id
        , ai.company_code
        , ai.policy_id
        , ai.transaction_status_rcd
        , ct.cashier_transaction_id
        , pv.patient_id
        -- more columns
FROM        dbo.ar_invoice AS ai
INNER JOIN  dbo.swe_cashier_transaction AS ct ON ct.invoice_id = ai.ar_invoice_id AND ct.split_date_time IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN  dbo.patient_visit AS pv ON pv.patient_visit_id = ct.patient_visit_id

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX XPKar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview ON dbo.ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview (ar_invoice_id, cashier_transaction_id)

CREATE INDEX XIE4ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview ON dbo.ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview (patient_id, transaction_status_rcd, company_code) INCLUDE (policy_id)
```

So far so good.

But every few days (and not at the same time of day), things go pear-shaped, the query takes minutes and actually times out (the command timeout of the provider is set to 10 minutes). When this happens, there is no blocking. I have an extended event session and this is my query

```
DECLARE @event_xml xml;

SELECT      @event_xml = CONVERT(xml, target_data)
FROM        sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
INNER JOIN  sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS t ON s.address = t.event_session_address
WHERE       s.name = 'Blocking over 10 seconds'

SELECT  DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), R.c.value('@timestamp', 'datetime')) AS time_stamp
    , R.c.value('(data[@name="blocked_process"]/value[1]/blocked-process-report[1]/blocked-process[1]/process)[1]/@spid', 'int') AS blocked_spid
    , R.c.value('(data[@name="blocked_process"]/value[1]/blocked-process-report[1]/blocked-process[1]/process[1]/inputbuf)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS blocked_inputbuf
    , R.c.value('(data[@name="blocked_process"]/value[1]/blocked-process-report[1]/blocked-process[1]/process[1]/@waitresource)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS wait_resource
    , R.c.value('(data[@name="blocked_process"]/value[1]/blocked-process-report[1]/blocking-process[1]/process)[1]/@spid', 'int') AS blocking_spid
    , R.c.value('(data[@name="blocked_process"]/value[1]/blocked-process-report[1]/blocking-process[1]/process[1]/inputbuf)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS blocking_inputbuf
    , R.c.query('.')
FROM    @event_xml.nodes('/RingBufferTarget/event') AS R(c)
ORDER BY R.c.value('@timestamp', 'datetime') DESC
```

This query is returning other cases of blocking, so I believe it's correct. At the time the problem (the timeouts) occur, there are no cases of blocking involving the query above, or any other query.

Since there is no blocking, I'm looking at the possibility of a bad query plans. I didn't find a bad plan in the cache (I had already recommended an sp_recompile on of the tables before I was given remote access), so I tried to think of the worst possible one: scans for every table. Applying the relevant options, here are the IO stats for this query:

```
Table 'patient_visit'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4559, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 7, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'swe_cashier_transaction'. Scan count 9, logical reads 24840, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 23660, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ar_invoice'. Scan count 9, logical reads 21247, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 7074, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'policy'. Scan count 9, logical reads 271, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

And here is the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJr29s_br

The customer has a beefy SQL Server 2012 box, plenty of cores (maxdop is set to 8), tons of memory. It eats this bad query for breakfast (takes around 350 msec).

For completeness, here are the row counts of the tables involved:

- ar_invoice: 2363527
- swe_cashier_transaction: 2946514
- patient_visit: 654976
- policy: 1038
- ar_invoice_cashier_transaction_visit_iview: 1999609

I also ran the query for a patient_id that returns the most rows, and for a patient_id that didn't exist (i.e. 0 rows). I ran these with the recompile option: in both cases the optimizer selected the same (good) execution plan.

So back to the question: there is no blocking, the query plan seems to be good (and even if it was bad, it wouldn't be bad to the extent this query takes 10 minutes), so what can cause this ?

The only thing a little unusual here is that, although the SQL doesn't select from the indexed view, the optimizer uses it anyway - and this is or should be a good thing. I know the Enterprise version claims it can do this, but this is the first time I've seen it in the wild (I've seen plenty of the opposite though: referencing an indexed view in SQL, but the optimizer selects from the view's underlying tables anyway). I'm tempted to believe that this is relevant.

Comment: None - there's no information in this question. No query, no table schema, no execution plan, no data/row sizes. Except `NOLOCK` - that's a bug. `NOLOCK` means `don't respect locks, read dirty and duplicate data while taking far more locks`. When you see this it means someone run into a performance problem and tried to cover it up by ignoring locks

Comment: This is not a coding problem, you won't be able to reproduce this with a few simple tables, a few rows of data and a query. I can't even reproduce it in the production database.
As for NOLOCK, it's not a bug. Our transaction isolation level is serializable (we're coming from COM+), and that's not something you change overnight in an ERP system. It's not ideal, but it's not a bug either.
What I'm hoping for is that someone else has had issues with indexed views and has some tips.

Comment: COM+ never required `SERIALIZABLE` **in the database**. Back in 2000 it used `SERIALIZABLE` itself which means database access could have a far less restrictive model, provided different services/components only worked with *their* data. In later years it allowed the full range of isolation levels. And yes, NOLOCK is a bug. It means you're going to read *incomplete, uncommitted data* and even the *same row twice* if the data has to move. NOLOCK itself is going to take extra locks at the page level and up.

Comment: The default isolation level in COM+ is serializable, and we were left with the default. This is not about NOLOCK

Comment: Only in the early 2000s. That didn't *force* the database connections to use SERIALIZABLE though. Besides, even in the 2000s (or is it especially in the 2000s?) people used optimistic concurrency with short connections anyway, so even SERIALIZABLE didn't cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: In any case, without any specific information it's impossible to help. The only usable information is `NOLOCK`. Check Aaron Bertrand's [Bad Habits: Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). He mentions the dirty reads, missing or double rows, the *extra* locks it takes and how to actually check them.

Comment: I was hoping the usable information would be:
- there is no blocking
- the query has a good execution plan
- the optimizer uses a suitable indexed view
and yet the query sometimes takes several minutes instead of a few msec

Comment: Could be a case of parameter sniffing, resulting in a bad pre-compiled execution plan for a parameter you pass in. Several options exist, optimizing for a specific parameter, or optimizing based on statistics rather than a specific parameter, recompiling on each execution. See [Query Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) for more what's available.

Comment: Thanks for that. I ruled out parameter sniffing, since I ran the query (with recompile) with both extremes of parameter values: a patient_id that had 0 rows in the indexed view, and the patient_id that had the most rows (around 600) in the indexed view. In both cases the optimizer created the same plan, and it's the plan I'm seeing when things go well. Statistics are up to date btw. I believe something else is at play here.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your setup, a few other things I would check:

- what is overall CPU and memory utilisation like on the box, could there be resource contention
- if your storage is on a SAN rather than local storage, is there contention at the storage end (this can happen if you have heavy reads/writes on the same disk arrays from different systems)

Comment: The server seemed responsive at the time and there were no reports of slowness in other areas of the system, but I will ask the customer to collect some perf counters next time it happens The storage is indeed on a SAN, I'll try to get some stats on that too. Thanks for your suggestions, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several other factors involved in slowing down a query. Personally I don't really trust the SQL Server's Optimization technique though. Normally I would recommend to optimize your query so that optimizer does NOT have to do hard work, for example use `Exists` / `In` on main table instead of joining and doing `distinct`/`group`ing, like,

```
select  distinct ia.AttributeCode, ia.AttributeDescription
from    ItemsTable as i 
        inner join ItemAttributesTable as ia on i.AttributeCode = ia.AttributeCode
where   i.Manufacturer = @paramMfr
        and i.MfrYear between @paramYearStart and @paramYearYend
```

instead of running a query like above run it like this

```
select  ia.AttributeCode, ia.AttributeDescription
from    ItemAttributesTable as ia
where   ia.AttributeCode in (
            select  i.AttributeCode
            from    ItemsTable as i
            where   i.Manufacturer = @paramMfr
                    and i.MfrYear between @paramYearStart and @paramYearYend
        )
```

I am NOT really expert in indexing, but for above case, I think only 1 index should be sufficient in `ItemsTable`

Another optimization can be done by removing the views and directly using the tables, because views may also be doing joins on other tables that are really not required here.

All in all, the main point is that when query optimizer is figuring out the best possible scenario and it may run into the case where it reaches to the timeout (which is called Optimizer TimeOut limit), in that case it may pick up a plan which is NOT really good at that specific time, which is why the plan cache should be used. That's the reason here I am recommending to focus on optimizing the query rather looking at the reasons why it's timing out.

Check this out as well https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2018/10/19/understanding-optimizer-timeout-and-how-complex-queries-can-be-affected-in-sql-server/

**Update-1:**

Recommendations:

1. Use `Exists` / `In`, even if you see the same execution plan as your current query, still this will help optimizer to almost always use the correct plan
2. Try eliminating the views and directly use the tables, with fewer select columns.
3. Make sure you have proper indexed defined as per the given parameters
4. Try breaking the query into smaller parts, for example pick the filtered data in temporary table and then grab rest of the details using temporary tables
5. Try googling "Timeout in Application not in SSMS" and see different hacks

Common causes of query timeout:

1. No indexing defined
2. Extracting too much data
3. There is/are lock(s) on one or more tables while you are trying to read data from those table(s)
4. Parameter type and Field type difference, for example, the column is varchar while parameter type is nvarchar
5. Parameter sniffing

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate it. Running the query with an IN () instead of a DISTINCT gives me the same execution plan and IO stats, as expected. That leaves the question: would this alternative SQL be less susceptible to the optimizer getting it wrong (bearing in mind that I still don't know what "wrong" looks like) ? Impossible to tell.
As for the optimizer timeout, this is such a simple query, I can't really see the optimizer running out of time finding the best plan. Compile time is around 5 msec.

Comment: As I said, I don't really trust the optimizer figuring out itself. It's NOT about the simple query, it's about the load the server has at that specific time, so probably sometimes simple query may also lead to timeout. BTW, you can also force specific plan all the time as mentioned in the article.

Comment: Ok, understood, That said, we have about 1000 different business tier method calls (4000 tables), each with several flavors of a query (built dynamically in the business tier based on input parameters). Many of these queries are orders of magnitude more complex than this one, and out of all of these, only a single query is causing significant problems from time to time: this one. If the server was under load to the extent the optimizer had to cut short its search for the best plan, I would expect total mayhem, but we're not seeing that.

Comment: Unfortunately no one can really help you out unless check all the related queries and scenarios physically. Anyway, I have updated my answer check it out.